# -JSONValue failed. Error is: Unexpected end of input

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I got the JSON result as `-JSONValue failed. Error is: Unexpected end of input`. Please direct me in right way.

I am new in parsing . I have to get Data from the server by POST method. I have following details. I have to pass zip with url

```
{"zip":"52435","methodIdentifier":"search_dealer"}

url : http://usaautoleads.com/api.php

method: post

web service name: search_dealer

response : {"success":"0","dealer":[info...]}
```

my code is here.

```
NSURL *myURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://usaautoleads.com/api.php"];

NSString *post =[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"52435"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

[request setURL:myURL]; 

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData]; 

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: wht is info in your response???? make it clear...

Comment: -JSONValue failed. Error is: Unexpected end of input

Comment: @InderKumarRathore i am getting nothing in my response string

Comment: if you are not getting anything in your response(server response) then what are you parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with your post string. Use this one

```
NSString *zip = @"52435";
NSString *methodID = @"search_dealer";
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"zip\":\"%@\",\"methodIdentifier\":\"%@\"}", zip, methodID];
```