# handle JSON response in project

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I am a new programmer. I get the following response from server. How can i get the value  of 0 index  "Mile High Motors of Butte" and "Mile High Motors of Dillion" from following

Thanks

```
{
dealer =     (
            {
        0 = "Mile High Motors of Butte";
        1 = "3883 Harrison";
        2 = Butte;
        3 = 59701;
        4 = MT;
        5 = "http://www.buttesmilehighchryslerjeepdodge.com";
        6 = 2;
        7 = 0;
        address = "3883 Harrison";
        city = Butte;
        distance = 0;
        id = 2;
        name = "Mile High Motors of Butte";
        state = MT;
        url = "http://www.buttesmilehighchryslerjeepdodge.com";
        zip = 59701;
    },

           {
        0 = "Mile High Motors of Dillon";
        1 = "790 N Montana St";
        2 = Dillon;
        3 = 59725;
        4 = Montana;
        5 = "http://www.MileHighDillon.com";
        6 = 13;
        7 = "60.1235269593172";
        address = "790 N Montana St";
        city = Dillon;
        distance = "60.1235269593172";
        id = 13;
        name = "Mile High Motors of Dillon";
        state = Montana;
        url = "http://www.MileHighDillon.com";
        zip = 59725;
    }
);
success = 1;
}
```

Comment: @RayToal True. I think he already deserialized the json object to cocoa

Comment: Sorry, commented before reading the tags.

Comment: I copy paste it from my console.please see my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432342/jsonvalue-failed-error-is-unexpected-end-of-input

Comment: because server response is lengthy . so i removed two tags from between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay let's see your structure (assuming that you have already deserialized your JSON string).
You have an `NSDictionary` with two keys (`dealer` & `success`). Now `dealer` key is an `NSArray` with two `NSDictionaries`. So based on that we could do:

```
NSDictionary *myJson; // Assuming that this is what you have posted

NSArray *dealers = [myJson valueForKey:@"dealer"];

// Now just grab whatever you need

NSString *dealerOne = [[dealers objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"0"]; //Mile High Motors of Butte
NSString *dealerTwo = [[dealers objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"0"]; //Mile High Motors of Dillon
```

Or you could just iterate your `dealers` array like this:

```
for (NSDictionary *dealer in dealers)
{
  NSString *dealerName = [dealer valueForKey:@"0"];
  // Do something useful
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSMutableArray yourStringArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //for getting texts what you want.  
    NSArray * array1 = [yourDictionary valueForKey:@"dealer"];// You will get array which has dictionary elements.
    for (NSDictionary *dealer in array1)// Write loop for getting your string.
    {
      NSString *dealerName = [dealer valueForKey:@"0"];
     [yourStringArray addObject:dealerName];
    }
```

I think it will be helpful to you.